# Intermittent Access Denied error from AWS S3

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have some Scala code running in Elastic Beanstalk (using Tomcat) that accesses S3 using the Java AWS SDK.  It was working perfectly for months.  Then, a few days ago, we started seeing some strange errors.  It can read and write to S3 about a third of the time.  The other two thirds of the time, it gets an access denied error when reading from S3.

The exceptions look like this: `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 6CAC5AB616FC6F23)`

All S3 operations use the same bucket.  The IAM role has full access to S3 (allowed to do any operation using any bucket).

We contacted Amazon support and they can't help us unless we provide a host ID and request ID that they can research.  But the exception only has a request ID.

I'm looking for one of two things: either a solution to the access denied errors, or a way to get a host ID we can give to Amazon support.  I already tried calling `s3Client.getCachedResponseMetadata(getObjectRequest)`, but it always returns `null` after the getObject call fails.

Comment: how are you providing the credentials to the app? is it possible that they get somehow corrupted along the way? also, what changes did you make (code, config) from the time this started happening until currently? [based on what you are observing the credentials are corrupted]

Comment: I get a credentials provider by calling KinesisConnectorConfiguration.AWS_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER (amazon-kinesis-connectors library).  The provider is passed to the AmazonS3Client constructor without modification.

There haven't been any code or config changes since June.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the Host ID by calling `AmazonS3Exception.getErrorResponseXml()`.  We're still working with Amazon to determine the root cause.

Comment: It turns out that the files we were trying to read from S3 had been encrypted.  We gave the app's role permission to the encryption key and that fixed the problem.